# Values/Dimens folder for Nexus 10

Tags: android, layout, screen, material-design

I am trying to design the app for Nexus 10. For dimensions I have made a `values-sw800dp` and put the dimensions in the **dimens.xml** file. However the device is not reading the dimension from dimens.xml file for the Nexus 10 instead it's reading it from **values-sw360dp/dimens.xml** folder.

What am I doing wrong? What is the values-sw<>dp folder for the Nexus 10?

Answer (score 1):

Nexus 10 has **~299 ppi** pixel density . so you can use **values-xhdpi** folder for that . see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)  Steven Byle provide us a very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

More common answer: to get know dp for any device, just install [Developer Tools app from market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roysolberg.android.developertools) and you always will know the properties of the device.
P.S.: to get to know how to calculate dimension pixels (dp), read this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels).

[image]